# How to leave a comment on a answer?

Tags: support, comments

I am quite new here, and I have a question about how to use this site in the right way.

I found a answer to a question that's is what I am looking for, but I have some doubts about the code. How can I leave a comment on this answer? I only have the possibility to edit, share or write my own answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You will be allowed to comment when your reputation will be at least 50, see here https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment